# How do I find a value inside class properties?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a long list of 100 students. I am building a Find dialog that searches for students by their name. Here are my class properties:

**My code**

```
public partial class FF : Window
{
    public FF()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<User> items = new List<User>();
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39 });
        items.Add(new User() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 13 });
        lvStudents.ItemsSource = items;

    }

    public class User
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

**My XAML**

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="10" Grid.RowSpan="10">
    <ListView Name="lvStudents">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="30" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

** Things I tried**

```
    private void FindStudent(string name)
    {
        if (stud.Name.Any(str => str.Contains(name)))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Student found!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Student not found!");
        }
    }
```

Every time I run the above code, I don't get any specific error. But I get wrong result that the student was not found. Why?

Comment: your `stud` variable in `Window_Loaded` method is local, but then assigned to a `DataContext` of your WPF window. But then, in `FindStudent` method you use some other variable called `stud`. Where is it populated?

Comment: Sorry, ignore that... It is outside the Loaded event in my original quote. The mistake is only on my StackOverFlow code, which I have corrected now

Comment: I think we're missing some code. Where does the `stud` in the `FindStudent` come from? (And what is it?). One thing is for certain `stud` in your `FindStudent` method is not your `List<Students>` from your `Window_Loaded` method (`List<T>` has no `Name` property)

Comment: I agree. But not able to determine what exactly I'm missing out here..

Comment: Well for starters it would be nice if we could see where the `stud` in the `FindStudent` method comes from? You have tagged this question with wpf, and I see a `DataContext` being set so I assume some controls are used with bound properties. Can you include the relevant wpf code? Also it could help if you post the relevant parts of the classes `FindStudent` and `Window_Loaded` are contained in. Because the main problem seems to be that you're not able to get your `List<Students>` into the `stud` used in the `FindStudent` method.

Comment: @Knoop Have updated question with complete source code

Comment: I have fixed it finally. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
if (stud.Any(st => st.Name.Contains(name)))
```

instead of

```
if (stud.Name.Any(str => str.Contains(name)))
```

With "using System.Linq;" of course

P.S. "stud" as we can see in the question, is List. We call Any() method on the list of students, and pass a lambda-predicate which checks name of every student.

Comment: `List<T>`  does not contain a property `Name` so `stud` in this method is not the original `List<Students>`. Fair assumption would be that `stud` here is of type `Students` and in that case this won't even compile.

Comment: Thinking about it it also doesn't seem to be of type `Students`. Could be that the code op posted doesn't compile in which case no assumptions can be made and I apologize since then this might be the correct answer after all.

Comment: Did you read my answer carefully? :)
List<T> does not contain. but class "Students" which is a type of list elements in our case has this property/ therefore, I write: if (stud.Any(st => st.Name.Contains(name))).


This code is calling Any() on List<Students>, and passing a lambda, And lambda calls Name on list items. And why did you minus me? :)

Comment: I did read it carefully. if `stud.Name.Any(str => str.Contains(name))` compiles (implied by op) then `stud` is not the `List<Students>` you think it is (if it is it wouldn't compile since it doesn't have a `Name` property). I don't know what it is though, we have to await response from the op.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. 
But I suspect, that it fails with compilation and runs the last successful build )

Comment: Thanks.. But this shows me an error: List<String> does not contain a definition for 'Name'

Comment: The problem is, that we dont know what the type you are working with. Better you show us more code. Is it WPF app?

Comment: Okay @hardaxan. Have updated my question with complete source code.

Comment: Yes, it's WPF application.

Comment: I have fixed it now... Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void connectDb()
{
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR DATABASE LOCATION/ DATABASE PATH");
     conn.Open(); // initalize your database connection

}

private void searchForStudentName()
{
   string name;// = your textbox that holds value of students name;
   this.connectDb(); //your connection into database
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from ['YOUR TABLE NAME'] where Name = @Name",conn);
   cmd.parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);
   dr= cmd.ExcecuteReader();


  if(dr.Read())//meaning, the system found the value of the input data/ name
  {
     ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(dr["NAME"].ToString);// name will be displayed in listview control
     listView1.items.add(lvi);
  }else
  {
    //there is no data found
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community Anyway. I suggest you to read the [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fixed the issue. Thanks to all those who contributed and answered me.

```
private void FindStudent(string name)
{
    User std = items.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name.Contains(name));
    if (std != null)
    {
        this.Title = "Student found!";
    }
    else
    {
        this.Title = "Student NOT found!";
    }
}
```